# Callback, return value and HTML5 executeSql function

Tags: javascript, html, callback, closures

I have a big problem. I know it's about callback, closure but I don't know how to solve the problem. Here is my code

```
$.Model.extend('Article',
{
     findAll : function(params, success, error){                
                var result = []
                db.transaction(function(tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('select * from contents', [],function(tx, rs) {
                        for(var i=0; i<rs.rows.length; i++) {
                            var row = rs.rows.item(i)
                            result[i] = {
                                id: row['id'],
                                title: row['title'],
                                body: row['body']
                            }
                        }
                    })
                })
                //here result is undefined
                alert(result)
                return result
    }
})
//undefined
var view = Article.findAll
```

I know that executeSql is asynchronous function, but I don't know how to save and return result of executeSql. I use javascript mvc and HTML offline database.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I Google'd "Javascript MVC" and found the library, but can't find anything in the JavaScript MVC docs about 'executeSql'. If you have docs handy, you should check to see if there is a way to make the tx.executeSql method run synchronously instead of asynchronous.

Comment: I know there is also synchronous method for executeSql, but safari and other webkit based browsers support only asynchronous. Code below works perfectly, thank you guys

Comment: Works perfectly? One might almost say, it was the "answer" ? ;)

Comment: The synchronous API only applies (in the spec) to web workers, not the window object, so that's not a possibility. http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/#databases

Answer (score 5):

The W3C web database spec talks about support for both Asynchronous and Synchronous database operations. [(See 4.3 and 4.4)](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#asynchronous-database-api)

If you can't use a synchronous implementation, then you might want to consider approaching the problem like this instead:

```
$.Model.extend('Article',
{
     findAll : function(params, success, error){                
                var result = []
                db.transaction(function(tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('select * from contents', [],function(tx, rs) {
                        for(var i=0; i<rs.rows.length; i++) {
                            var row = rs.rows.item(i)
                            result[i] = {
                                id: row['id'],
                                title: row['title'],
                                body: row['body']
                            }
                        }

                        success(result); //toss the result into the 'success' callback
                    })
                })
                //here result is undefined
                alert(result)
                return result
    }
})

Article.findAll([], function(view) {
        //...
    }, function() {
        //error occured
    });
```

Comment: oh man finally worked with your code! important was i did not run the code in the function was sill outside!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues, but you might want to use this little wrapper library that makes life easier ;)

http://github.com/grosser/arjs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, especially on mobile development projects.  I created a library that eliminates the need for callbacks:
http://code.google.com/p/proto-q/

This made my code easier to troubleshoot, maintain, and enhance.

I added support for AJAX, web workers, script injection, and the storage APIs.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to use the result synchronously, that is your accessing result before its defined (actually in your code example its not undefined, its an empty array) though I expect thats because you had moved the declaration from its original position trying to figure out what was happening.

Try this modified example:-

```
$.Model.extend('Article',
{
    findAll : function(params, success, error){                
            db.transaction(function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('select * from contents', [], function(tx, rs) {
                    var result = [];
                    for(var i=0; i<rs.rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = rs.rows.item(i)
                        result.push({
                            id: row['id'],
                            title: row['title'],
                            body: row['body']
                        });
                    }
                    success(result);
                });
            });
    }
});

Article.findAll({}, function(result) { 
    // process result here
});
```

Article.findAll() is now an asynchronous function, and its callback (closure) receives the results.

Comment: Oh I should have read the other example first, as it is essentially the same!