# Web db - getting the data back

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-sql

Here is the code

```
    onError = function(tx, e) {
        alert('Something unexpected happened: ' + e.message );
    }

    var webdb = openDatabase(dbName, '1.0' , dbDesc , dbSize);

    var colourArray = new Array();

    webdb.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM colours', 
                      [], 
                      function(tx,rs) {
                        var ctn = rs.rows.length;
                        for (var i=0; i < ctn; i++) {
                            var row = rs.rows.item(i);                
                            colourArray.push([row.id , row.title]);
                        }   
                      }, 
                      onError);
    });
    /**
     * the array looks like [[1,'red'],[2,'white'],[3,'black'] ...]
     */
     var ColourStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({fields: ['key', 'val'],
                                               data: colourArray});
```

The table "colours" contain colour name and hash code. And it was suppose to be use by a ExtJS Ext.data.ArrayStore then populate other drop downs on a massive form.

My problem is - I couldn't get the data back as an array. The variable "colourArray" is empty ... I know I hit some javascript closure , loop problem ... but just couldn't figure out how to get that inner loop value back. Try a lot of return -> return -> return function and more return. None of them works.

Comment: Just found the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898178/callback-return-value-and-html5-executesql-function

Comment: [sign...]  just this one thing makes the whole HTML5 not ready for prime time ... really think about the pain just to get a variable out?

Comment: Just tested the activeRecord clone. doesn't work either. Cos the problem I have is. I have a global property (variable). I need to put the result set into the variable (property) then available to use by other methods (functions) later on. When you try to console.log(variable) before - empty. After - undefined. In the middle (while still inside the executeSql called back statement. Exactly what I wanted - filled with data.

Comment: Try many things in the last two days. Even put the return data in a hidden div and try to get them back later. No luck. Just not doing what you would expect from a "sql" engine ... switch to Google gear for the time being and HOPE! someone is listening that they create a piece of useless technology. Thanks again browser makers and the useless w3c

Answer (score 0):

executeSQL is asynchronous.  You need to create ColourStore in the function(tx,rs) callback function.  If you need the data available globally, you can't init your app until executeSQL calls the callback function. Example:

```
Ext.onReady( function() {
    var webdb = openDatabase(dbName, '1.0' , dbDesc , dbSize);

    var colourArray = new Array();
    var ColourStore;

    webdb.transaction( function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM colours',
        [], function(tx,rs) {
            var ctn = rs.rows.length;
            for (var i=0; i < ctn; i++) {
                var row = rs.rows.item(i);
                colourArray.push([row.id , row.title]);
            }
            //INIT YOUR APP HERE IN ORDER TO HAVE ACCESS TO colourArray values
            ColourStore = new Ext....
            YourApp.init();
        },
        onError);
    });
}, this);
```

Comment: I wish it was this simple. There are 17 queries in total ... It just not possible to separate the logic like what you said. Yes one is OK. If I only have one drop down. But there are more than 17 of them ... on a 3 pages massive form.

Comment: OK, I did another test. Basically same as before. But inside the loop. I just jQuery.data();

Comment: I hate the keyboard capture of this bloody comment box!!!!! You can press enter. Stupid. Anyway, the code inside the loop is. jQuery('body').data({'returnData': rowData}); if you try to get it back immediately. It doesn't work. but if you attach it to a button or something. click and the data return the way you want it. So I am sure I am onto something here. It just need to figure out why I can't the data back right after the data been attach by jQuery. Any guru out there?

Comment: post more code?  You need to do all of your variable assignments in the callback function. I don't know how to explain any better...  Please upvote the answer as it is correct based on your original question

Comment: OK I finally found a work round. Share it here with all those lost souls out there. If you couple that with a localStorage - right after you fetch the data. Make the object as string (sorry could not store as object at all) then store it in a localStorage. Then you could fetch it from the localStorage anywhere else in your app. How to string to object ... you should know. Hope this help someone out there.

Comment: Mmm seems like I was wrong again. You could not get it back immediately. Just like all the things I have tried. Right. Abandon ship.

Comment: you need to learn how to use stackoverflow.  You are just posting noise and not helping those who try to help you!

Comment: yeah whatever. James. Thanks a bunch.