# How to ensure that function a has been run before function b..?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm having some trouble with the following javascript code..

```
        var returnValue = false;
        function hasItem(id) {
            //I want this entire function to run first
            db.transaction(function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM library WHERE id == "+id,[],function(tx, results) {
                    returnvalue = results.rows.length>0; 

                },errorCB);
            },errorCB,successCB);

            //then this
            return returnvalue;
        }
```

But the sql-function appears to run in a separate thread, making the function return false all the time.. is there any way "to force a wait"..?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898178/callback-return-value-and-html5-executesql-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way "to force a wait"..?

No. What you must do is change your `hasItem` function so that it accepts a callback that provides the information, instead of returning a value.

It's a bit tricky not knowing what your `errorCB` and `successCB` callbacks do, but something along these lines:

```
function hasItem(id, callback) {
    var returnValue = false;
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM library WHERE id == "+id,[],function(tx, results) {
            returnValue = results.rows.length > 0; 
        },failed);
    },failed,function() {
        successCB();
        callback(returnValue);
    });

    function failed() {
        errorCB();
        callback(null); // Or whatever you want to use to send back the failure
    }
}
```

Then, instead of this

```
if (hasItem("foo")) {
    // Do something knowing it has the item
}
else {
    // Do something knowing it doesn't have the item
}
```

You use it like this:

```
hasItem("foo", function(flag) {
    if (flag) {
        // Do something knowing it has the item
    }
    else {
        // Do something knowing it doesn't have the item
        // (or the call failed)
    }
});
```

If you want to tell, in the callback, whether the call *failed*:

```
hasItem("foo", function(flag) {
    if (flag === null) {
        // The call failed
    }
    else if (flag) {
        // Do something knowing it has the item
    }
    else {
        // Do something knowing it doesn't have the item
    }
});
```

Comment: The `db.transaction` already seems to have success/error callbacks, OP should use those.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz: Yeah, it was hard to tell what those might do, but I suspect they may be fairly generic. I added some sample code interacting with them.