# store json data in sqlite(phonegap app)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sqlite, cordova

How can I store the JSON data that is decoded into SQLite Database. The app is built using phonegap.

Here is the function in which the json data is getting decoded.

```
function onNotification(e) {               
    switch( e.event )
    {
        case 'message':                                                 
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
            var j=JSON.stringify(e);
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG DECODED: ' + j + '</li>');
            //android only
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
            //amazon-fireos only
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
            break;
    }
}
```

Here the JSON message is decoded and stored to a variable `j`. It is getting displayed properly. I want to store that into SQLite database. I tried by adding the plugin but it is showing error like *"This is not responding"*. How can I store the message into SQL database.

Here is what I get when I try to display `j`.

> MESSAGE -> MSG: undefined
>
> MESSAGE -> MSG DECODED:
>   {"payload":{"0":{"medicine_name":null},"1":{"tm_1":null},"2":{"tm_2":null},"3":{"tm_3":null},"4":{"dosage":null},"5":{"medicine_name":null},"6":{"tm_1":null},"7":{"tm_2":null},"8":{"tm_3":null},"9":{"dosage":null},"10":{"medicine_name":null},"11":{"tm_1":null},"12":{"tm_2":null},"13":{"tm_3":null},"14":{"dosage":null},"15":{"medicine_name":null},"16":{"tm_1":null},"17":{"tm_2":null},"18":{"tm_3":null},"19":{"dosage":null},"20":{"medicine_name":null},"21":{"tm_1":null},"22":{"tm_2":null},"23":{"tm_3":null},"24":{"dosage":null},"25":{"medicine_name":null},"26":{"tm_1":null},"27":{"tm_2":null},"28":{"tm_3":null},"29":{"dosage":null},"30":{"medicine_name":null},"31":{"tm_1":null},"32":{"tm_2":null},"33":{"tm_3":null},"34":{"dosage":null},"35":{"diagnosis":null},"36":{"instructions":null}},"

Please help.

This is what i tried to do for storing it into SQL. But it didnt work

```
$("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "drrem.db", location: 1});
db.transaction(function(tx)
{
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Medicine');
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (medicine_name text,tm_1 integer,tm_2 integer,tm_3 integer,dosage text,diagnosis text,instructions text)');
     var j=[hash, JSON.stringify(e, null, "")];
     tx.executeSql("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Medicine (medicine_name,tm_1,tm_2,tm_3,dosage,diagnosis,instructions) VALUES (?, ?)", j, function(tx, result)
      {
            console.log("insertId: " + result.insertId + " -- probably 1");
            console.log("rowsAffected: " + result.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");
      });
});
```

Comment: why you have only 2 `(?, ?)`, when you insert 7 columns? shouldn't be `(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`?

Comment: Oh sorry. I didnt notice that. How about the rest? Is it correct?

Comment: Still it is showing the error "It has stopped working"

Comment: I dont have 20 reputation :(

Comment: @adricadar can i share you the github repo link? the whole code is there.. this is just a small part of it. Even the switch cases comprise of 3 condition. any way to help me? its very urgent :(

Comment: i think instead of `var j=[hash, JSON.stringify(e, null, "")];` you should have `var j = JSON.stringify(e)`. The next problem is that you need to take the list of messages from `e.payload` and make a iteration `for` each message and insert it.

Comment: I will post an answer with a complet snnipet of code ( to have a same vision about code), please give me a feedback about the results.

Comment: @adricadar Thanks a ton.. If its not possible here to answer,I have send a request in fb. Please do check :) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is:

You try to insert `e` wich have a `payload` that contains **an array**.
You should *iterate* over array and `for` each message insert it.

Also you have `(?, ?)` and should be `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

**Notes:**

1) You get `MSG: undefined` because you display message from `e.payload.message` if you look closely there is no property `message`, should be `e.payload`.

```
$("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + JSON.stringify(e.payload) + '</li>');
```

2) You don't neet to use `JSON.stringify` because `tx.executeSql` expects the data you insert to be an `array` (ex `[ 'medicine_value', 'tm_1_value1', ... ]`

3) This table don't contains `id` column (add an `id unique` to table)

4) If you want to see if data is inserted, [make a select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898178/callback-return-value-and-html5-executesql-function)

```
$("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "drrem.db", location: 1});
db.transaction(function(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Medicine');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id unique, medicine_name text,tm_1 integer,tm_2 integer,tm_3 integer,dosage text,diagnosis text,instructions text)');


    var totalItems = 5;
    var currentArray = [];
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(currentArray);
    currentArray.push(arr.length);
    for (var key in e.payload) {
        var prop = e.payload[key]; 
        for (var name in prop) {
            currentArray.push(prop[name]);
            if(i%totalItems == 0) {
                i = 0;
                currentArray.push(null);
                currentArray.push(null);
                currentArray = [];
                arr.push(currentArray);
                currentArray.push(arr.length);
            }
        }   
        i++;
    };
    arr.pop();

    for(var idx = 0; idx < arr.length; idx++)
    {  
        var j=arr[idx];
        tx.executeSql("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Medicine (id,medicine_name,tm_1,tm_2,tm_3,dosage,diagnosis,instructions) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", j, function(tx, result)
         {
             console.log("Insert succeed");
             console.log(result);
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried this. But it is not getting executed I guess.  Should I have to call the db.transaction() ? If so,how ? Nothing is getting displayed now.

Comment: I have tried that also,but it is not getting invoked. The app is just showing "MSG:undefined".  If it is getting stored in db,then insertId and rowsAffected should be displayed right? Sorry If I am wrong,I'm very new to this. 

*Actually each medicine has dosage only. Instruction and Diagnosis are same for every medicine.

Comment: So we dont have to use JSON.stringify?

Comment: Actually the data is being received from the website. Please do check this page : http://www.drreminder.in/prescription.php

This is the format in which the data will be send.

Comment: I checked with the updated code. Now it is showing .
MSG : [object Object]
How can I check whether it got inserted into the db?

Comment: can u help me with the code? i'm kinda confused n meeting the deadline. Thank you

Comment: one last help..! can you check this code and tell me whether its correct?
http://pastebin.com/8eg4rjTH
I tried adding console.log inside db.transaction() but its not showing up. Can you check whether there is any error? Last help..:) Thank you